# Vulnerability in react when I try using MUI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I was trying to do a react project and I installed MUI and MUI icons using `npm install @mui/material` and `npm install @mui/icons-material` respectively. I imported the `SearchIcon`, but now I get this message on my react page:

> ./node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/index.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' in 'C:\Users\Atharva\OneDrive\Desktop\React Course\amazon-clone\node_modules@mui\styled-engine'

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";

function Header() {
    return (
        <div className='header'>
            <img 
             className="header__logo" 
             src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/amazon/amazon_PNG25.png" 
            />

            <div className="header__search">
                <input       
                 className="header__searchInpu t" type="text" />
                
                <SearchIcon className="header__searchIcon" />
            </div>

            <div className="header__nav">

             <div className='header__option'>
               <span className='header__optionOne'>
                   Hello Guest
               </span>

               <span className='header__optionTwo'>
                   Sign In
               </span>
             </div>

             <div className='header__option'>
             <span className='header__optionOne'>
                   Returns
               </span>

               <span className='header__optionTwo'>
                   Orders
               </span>
             </div>

             <div className='header__option'>
             <span className='header__optionOne'>
                   Your
               </span>

               <span className='header__optionTwo'>
                   Prime
               </span>   
             </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `npm install @emotion/react` and repeat if you get the same message for other package after.

MUI has a lot of peer dependencies you have to install manually.

Comment: thanks I'll be sure to try this :)